# How can I install the tensorflow object detection API on Google colab?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection-api

I tried running tensorflow object detection API on Colab according to 
[Inline Link](https://github.com/RomRoc/objdet_train_tensorflow_colab/blob/master/objdet_custom_tf_colab.ipynb)

I got such an error at the first Install required packages.
 How can I solve it?

Background : Python2 , GPU

```
/root
fatal: destination path 'models' already exists and is not an empty directory.
/root/models/research
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
ImportError: No module named object_detection.builders
```

Comment: I did not code it for some reason and I omitted it.
I ran the code of Install required packages for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear about from which directory you are executing the command.
if you executing it from content directory then go to model and then to research directory.

```
%cd ~/models/research
!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

If you don't have model directory clone it by using

```
!git clone --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
```